# PhpMyAdmin remote access denied but command cli granted

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, remote-access

I have 2 mariadb servers :

- server1 is public (with apache, php, etc... and a public ip)
- server2 is private (only with mariadb, and only a private ip)

server2 is accessible by ssh only via server1

i installed phpmyadmin on server1, and i want to manage dbs on server2 with it

i already followed this : [remote phpmyadmin](http://sforsuresh.in/access-remote-mysql-server-using-local-phpmyadmin/)

i granted all privileges on server2 to server1's mariadb root user

i can access it with mysql cli from server1 to server2 ('mysql --host=server2ip -u root -p'), but i get 'access denied' when using phpmyadmin... any idea ?

even if i used 'config' auth_type in config.inc.php, i still have the login form on phpmyadmin when i switch to remote host, is it normal ? (i have to give username, password and to select the host : localhost or remote host)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved... the answer was... SELinux !

I installed the last version of phpMyadmin, which gave me more details about the error (#2002), then after a search on SO :

[Error 2002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45151797/phpmyadmin-2002-error-for-remote-server)

Maybe it'll help someone !